# NSMutableArray gets reset after calling modalViewController

Tags: objective-c, ipad, methods, nsmutablearray, modalviewcontroller

**IT IS SOLVED BY @T-X. I've marked the changes with "// SOLUTION" in the code!!!**

I have the following issue, if I presentModalViewController, the NSMutableArray "projectsArray" gets reset.

Here is my code:

Here the .h file:

```
    // ViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class AddProject;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
    IBOutlet UITableView *projectsTableView;
    UIAlertView *reallyDelete;

    BOOL candelButtonClicked;
    NSIndexPath *actualIndexPath;

    NSMutableArray *projectsArray;
    NSInteger ID;
    NSString *NAME;

    AddProject *addProject;
    **ViewController *viewContr; // SOLUTION**
}
- (IBAction)addNewProject:(id)sender;

- (void)addToTableView:(NSString *)projectName;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIAlertView *reallyDelete;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger cancelButtonIndex;

@property IBOutlet UITableView *projectsTableView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) AddProject *addProject;
**@property (nonatomic, retain) ViewController *viewContr; // SOLUTION**

@end
```

Here the .m file:

```
    // ViewController.m
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomTableCell.h"
#import "AddProject.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

**@synthesize viewContr; // SOLUTION**

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    projectsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    ViewController *element = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    element->ID = 1;
    element->NAME = @"Demo project";
    NSLog(@"viewdidload");
    [projectsArray addObject:element];

    NSLog(@"1. Array length: %d", [projectsArray count]);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([projectsArray count] < 1) {
        NSLog(@"2. Array length: 0");
        return 0;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"2. Array length: %d", [projectsArray count]);
        return [projectsArray count];
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 78;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *customTableCellIdentifier = @"CustomTableCell";

    CustomTableCell *cell = (CustomTableCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:customTableCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    ViewController *element = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    element = [projectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = element->NAME;
    cell.prepTimeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", element->ID];

    NSLog(@"3. Array length: %d", [projectsArray count]);

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source

        reallyDelete = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Deleting" message:@"Do your really want to delete that row?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
        [reallyDelete show];

        actualIndexPath = indexPath;
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (buttonIndex != [reallyDelete cancelButtonIndex])
    {
        //If "Yes" clicked delete
        [projectsArray removeObjectAtIndex:actualIndexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"delete row");

        [self.projectsTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:actualIndexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:YES];
        [self.projectsTableView reloadData];
    }
}

#pragma mark Edit

- (IBAction)addNewProject:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"4. Array length: %d", [projectsArray count]);

    AddProject *addProjectView = [[AddProject alloc] initWithNibName:@"AddProject" bundle:nil];
    NSLog(@"4.1 Array length: %d", [projectsArray count]);
    addProjectView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    NSLog(@"4.2 Array length: %d", [projectsArray count]);
    addProjectView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
    NSLog(@"4.3 Array length: %d", [projectsArray count]);
    **addProjectView.viewContr = self; // SOLUTION**
    [self presentModalViewController:addProjectView animated:YES];
    NSLog(@"4.4 Array length: %d", [projectsArray count]);
    addProjectView.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(addProjectView.view.center.x/2.5, addProjectView.view.center.y/3, 800, 600);
    NSLog(@"4.5 Array length: %d", [projectsArray count]);
}

- (void)addToTableView:(NSString *)projectName
{
    NSLog(@"Project Array: %@", projectsArray);
    NSLog(@"addToTableView: %@", projectName);    
    NSLog(@"5. Array length: %d", [projectsArray count]);

    ViewController *element = [[ViewController alloc] init];

    element->ID = 2;
    element->NAME = projectName;

    [projectsArray addObject:element];

    NSLog(@"6. Array length: %d", [projectsArray count]);

    [self.projectsTableView reloadData];
    [self.projectsTableView setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setProjectsTableView:nil];
    self.projectsTableView = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

Here the .h file of the modal presented view:

```
    // AddProject.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class ViewController;

@interface AddProject : UIViewController
{    
    IBOutlet UITextField *projectName;

    ViewController *viewContr;
}

- (IBAction)back:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)next:(id)sender;

@property (nonatomic, retain) ViewController *viewContr;

@end
```

The .m file of the modal presented file:

```
    // AddProject.m
#import "AddProject.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface AddProject ()

@end

@implementation AddProject

**@synthesize viewContr; // SOLUTION I've mist to synthesize it**

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    **// SOLUTION no new allocation/init of ViewController**
}

- (IBAction)back:(id)sender
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (IBAction)next:(id)sender
{
    [viewContr addToTableView:projectName.text];
    [viewContr.projectsTableView reloadData];
    [viewContr.projectsTableView setNeedsDisplay];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    projectName = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

@end
```

I've tested the code by using breakpoints and I could locate the issue when the AddProject class "viewDidLoad" starts loading. But I don't know why it resets the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You navigate from `ViewController` Screen to `Add project` Screen. In `Add Project` Screen, you add a new project and want to delegate back this information to the `ViewController` Screen where you came from.

Now, you are trying to have an instance of `ViewController` in your `AddProject`, which you newly instantiate in `viewDidLoad` method and when project is added, you provide the information to it by calling `- (void)addToTableView:(NSString *)projectName` on it.
This doesn't work because - The instance of `ViewController` you allocated is a new instance and not the one you navigated from. When you do `alloc + init` you get a new object. Thus, although you get `addToTableView:` called on your `ViewController`, it doesn't work because the `ViewController` instance that is receiving this message is a new instance and not the one you navigated from.

Thus, all you needed to do is - have a `ViewController` property in your `Add Project`, which you would set before navigating. And then you can send message to this property - As explained in [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5086958#5086958) transcript.

I would like to say - However this thing works, it provides tight coupling between the two controllers.

Ideally, This cane be done by making `ViewController` (where you go navigate from) as a delegate of `Add Project` (where you navigate to). And then `Add Project` can delegate the added project to it's delegate by something like `- (void) addProjectController:(AddProjectViewController *) controller didAddProject:(NSString *) projectName`. This provides lose coupling between the two view controllers. To understand delegation concept, refer to [Delegates and Datasources](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html). Alternatively, search for other Stack overflow posts.

Answer (score 1):

You should allocate projectsArray in the init method of the view controller, not in in viewDidLoad. `projectsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` allocated a new empty array tach time the view is loaded.

Comment: It isn't bad to instantiate in `viewDidLoad` method. View's are loaded only once (when the view controller's view is requested) and again only when they get unloaded due to low memory. In such cases, it becomes the programmers responsibility to release them in `viewDidUnload` method or in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method, depending on if it can be recreated easily or some other reason. `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidUnload` are a part of view life cycle methods.

Comment: Allocations in `viewDidLoad` thus also gives you opportunity to have the allocation made in them to be released in `viewDidUnload` method, which is a good practice, as when memory is low, unwanted allocations should be released to free up memory. In case you allocate in `init` method, question arises is where would you `release` them in low memory situations and have them recreated again?

Comment: You are right, but from the question I had the impression that projectArray should persist during the entire lifetime of the view controller.

Comment: Yes, it should persist as user would lose all added projects if it gets deallocated. Either he can do `if(!projectsArray) { // allocate projectsArray ... }` in `viewDidLoad` method to prevent it from getting allocated (and hence losing previously added objects) every time view is loaded OR move it into `init` method as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Okay my issue is fixed through the stackoverflow chat. The tips for the final solution came from user @T-X. I've added the tips in the code in my question. They are marked with "// SOLUTION".

> In Add Project View controller's viewDidLoad method, remove the line
> `viewContr = [[ViewController alloc] init];`. Now make the variable
> `viewContr` in your `ViewController` class a property. Also synthesize
> it. And finally in the `- (IBAction)addNewProject:(id)sender` method,
> before presenting the controller, do `- addProjectView.viewContr = self;`. It will solve your issue.

(quote from [chat.stackoverflow](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5086958#5086958) | [@T-X](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1082071/t-x))